# Регулярное выражение на php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не получается составить регулярное выражение такого вида xx.xx.xxx,
где x - может быть любой латинский или русский символ любого регистра или цифра. Но обязательно должно быть 2 символа, далее точка => 2 символа => точка => 3 символа
Составил следующее выражение -

```
var_dump(preg_match('/^([а-я]*[А-Я]*[A-Z]*[a-z]*ё*Ё*[0-9]*){2}.([а-я]*[А-Я]*[A-Z]*[a-z]*ё*Ё*[0-9]*){2}.([а-я]*[А-Я]*[A-Z]*[a-z]*ё*Ё*[0-9]*){3}$/u', 'd1.df.dfd'));
```

Выражение работает кооректно, но если удалить 1 символ вконце, например d1.df.df, то оно возвращает 1, хотя должно 0. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поиск двух групп: `(?:[\pL\d]{2}\.){2}`
Поиск трёх буквенно-числовых символов: `[\pL\d]{3}`
Модификаторы: `i` - регистронезависимый; `u` - поиск символов юникода.

---

`(?:...)` - это конструкция НЕ сохраняющих скобок, которая используется только для группировки символов. А простые скобки `(...)` помимо группировки ещё и выполняют захват соответствующих подстрок. `\pL` и `\d` - это буквенные и числовые символьные классы соответственно.

```
$str = 'xx.xx.xxx';

$patt = '~(?:[\pL\d]{2}\.){2}[\pL\d]{3}~iu';
preg_match($patt, $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Новый синтаксис какой-то, но работает)

Comment: @tirael8 если что-то не понятно, спрашивайте, я в ответе допишу :)

Comment: Мне полностью этот синтаксис не понятен) нужно будет почитать. Это в какой-то новой версии php такое вышло? знак ?: pL, и т.д

Comment: Вижу, Вы выше написали описание, спс